# Python print json data from requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I keep scratching my head why it is not printing json content I need. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

This is the dictionary

```
> "listinginfo": {
>     "438309609514180554": {
>       "listingid": "438309609514180554",
>       "price": 35,
>       "fee": 4,
>       "publisher_fee_app": 730,
>       "publisher_fee_percent": "0.10000000149011612",
>       "currencyid": "2003",
>       "steam_fee": 1,
>       "publisher_fee": 3,
>       "converted_price": 50,
>       "converted_fee": 7,
>       "converted_currencyid": "2020",
>       "converted_steam_fee": 2,
>       "converted_publisher_fee": 5,
>       "converted_price_per_unit": 50,
>       "converted_fee_per_unit": 7,
>       "converted_steam_fee_per_unit": 2,
>       "converted_publisher_fee_per_unit": 5,
>       "asset": {
>         "currency": 0,
>         "appid": 730,
>         "contextid": "2",
>         "id": "1579403640",
>         "amount": "1",
>         "market_actions": [
>           {
```

The code + I need the values for the keys I want to print:

```
while 1:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    listingInfoStr = r.content
    result= ujson.loads(listingInfoStr)
    listingInfoJson= result['listinginfo']
    for listingdata in listingInfoJson: 
        print listingdata.get('listingId')
        print listingdata.get('subTotal') 
        print listingdata.get('feeAmount')
        print listingdata.get('totalPrice')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Cause listingInfoJson not iterable? it's just a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it looks like listingInfoJson comes back as a dict not a list. So when you iterate over it it's just pulling the keys.

You're calling the .get method on a unicode object, which will give you an AttributeError. You can run this code in to different ways:

```
for listingdata in listingInfoJson: 
    print listingInfoJson[listingdata].get('listingid')
    print listingInfoJson[listingdata].get('subTotal') 
    print listingInfoJson[listingdata].get('feeAmount')
    print listingInfoJson[listingdata].get('totalPrice')
```

or the better way of (edited for comments):

```
if listingInfoJson:
    for key, value in listingInfoJson.iteritems():
        print value.get('listingid')
        print value.get('subTotal') 
        print value.get('feeAmount')
        print value.get('totalPrice')
else:
    print "listingInfoJson is empty"
```

I'd also check your key values, `listingId` should be `listingid`

Comment: Thanks, worked ! i prefer the "data.iteritems()" way you just showed me, i'm going to research this more, thank you again.

Comment: Wanted to ask you, currently "for" statement prints the values, is it possible to add "else" statement+print"no key/value found" if there are not key, value ?

Comment: Updated for what I think you meant.

Comment: Awesome! tried it and it's perfect ! Gracias mr.TimberlakeCoding !

Answer (score 3):

You may use [requests.Response.json](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) method to get parsed JSON:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
listingInfoJson = r.json()['listinginfo']
```

Comment: please note that `listingInfoJson` will actually be a Python dict, and not a JSON string.

Comment: I don't want to use any other json parser apart from ujson, sorry.